# Quicksort algorithm (C#)

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort

I would like to ask what's actually wrong on this code. I tried to understand quicksort (2-way) by myself so I looked into this page: http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/#disqus_thread after that I tried to code it by myself and landed here:

```
    public void Sort(Comparison<TList> del, long l, long r)
    {
        // inspired by: http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/
        if (l >= r) return;

        // partitioning
        for(long i = l + 1; i <= r; i++)
        {
            if (del.Invoke(this[i], this[l]) < 0)
            {
                Swap(i, l);
            }
        }

        // recursion
        Sort(del, l, l - 1);
        Sort(del, l + 1, r);
    }
```

Then I looked into the comments on the mentioned website and found this:

```
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);

    last = left;

    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if (strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last - 1);
    qsort(v, last + 1, right);
}
```

and now I'm really curious why my code is still working, tested it with this (it's included in a linked list by the way):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList<int> obj;

        do
        {
            obj = MyList.Random(100, 0, 100);
            obj.Sort(stdc);
            obj.Sort(stdc);
        } while (obj.IsSorted(stdc));

        Log("Not sorted", obj);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

and this:

```
    public bool IsSorted(Comparison<TList> del)
    {
        var el = start;

        if (el != null)
        {
            while (el.Next != null)
            {
                if (del.Invoke(el.Value, el.Next.Value) > 0) // eq. to this[i] > this[i + 1]
                    return false;
                el = el.Next;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and this:

```
    public static MyList<int> Random(int num, int min = 0, int max = 1)
    {
        var res = new MyList<int>();
        var rand = new Random();

        while (num > 0)
        {
            res.Add(rand.Next(min, max));
            num--;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: What problems are you running into? Don't just dump a bunch of code and ask "what's wrong with this?"

Answer (score 0):

Your quicksort code is not really quicksort, and it will be slow. The line

```
        Sort(del, l, l - 1);
```

will not do anything, since the recursed into call will detect l >= (l-1). The line

```
        Sort(del, l + 1, r);
```

only reduces the size of the partition [l,r] by one to [l+1,r], so the time complexity will always be O(n^2), but it looks like it will work, just slowly.

The qsort() function swaps the left and middle values, this will avoid worst case issue if data is already sorted, but doesn't do much else. The key is that it updates "last", so that when partition is completed, the value at v[last] will be the pivot value, and then it makes recursive calls using "last" instead of "left" or in your code's case, "l".

The qsort shown is a variation of Lomuto partition scheme. Take a look at the wiki article which also includes the alternate Hoare partition scheme:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm

Comment: I am still curious why it is sorting anyways. But yeah, I am getting your point why it will not do anything.

Comment: well translated it now...

            long i, last;

            if (l >= r)
                return;
            Swap(l, (l + r) / 2);

            last = l;

            for (i = l + 1; i <= r; i++)
                if (del.Invoke(this[i], this[l]) < 0)
                    Swap(i, ++last);

            Swap(l, last);
            Sort(del, l, last - 1);

Comment: well the thing is, I want to UNDERSTAND that algorithm and not just copy/paste it... that's why I started to write my own linked list...

Comment: @MarIno - the reason the first code example works is because it ends up swapping the smallest element into this[l], then makes a recursive call for [l+1, r], which swaps the next to smallest value into this[l+1], and so on, until the last swap puts the next to largest value into this[r-1], with the largest value ending up in this[r].

Comment: @MarIno - I suggest using the Wiki algorithm I linked to in my answer. The wiki article includes an explanation for each algorithm.